# Are Outlook forms supported on some mobile phones?

Tags: mobile, outlook, outlook-form

I would like to create some Outlook forms to automate company processes.

Can the Outlook forms be used on some mobile phones? or are they only supported on Outlook in the desktop?

Answer (score 1):

I've written apps for Android, iOS and JME (J2ME) and I'm not aware of any ability to use Outlook forms on mobile phones. Having said that, I haven't tried my hand at developing on Windows 7/8 phones yet. If it is supported anywhere, I guess that's where it would be.

Good luck!